# How to split into a 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a program for shopping lists :)

The data will be like:

```
Amanda, Bananas, Apples, Oranges
Steve, Mushrooms, Pork, Spaghetti, Sauce
Dave, Onions, Eggs, Bread, Bacon
```

This is what I have so far

```
file = open(filename, "r")
readfile = file.read()
shlist = readfile.splitlines()
```

So I have created a list where each person's shopping is an item in the list.

Is it possible to split these into another list while still being items of a list themselves? I tried to add the following:

```
for shopping in shlist:
    shopping.split(,)
```

But I am receiving an error.

Alternately I could just use the index of the commas to deduce the location & length of the items. I am not sure which would be best.

Comment: [ [Amanda,Bananas, Apples, Oranges], [Steve, Mushrooms, Pork, Spaghetti, Sauce], [Dave, Onions, Eggs, Bread, Bacon] ] - Like a 2D list

Answer (score 3):

Well, you're getting an error because you meant to type `.split(',')`, but that still won't solve your problem.  A call to split() takes a string a generates a list of strings as a result.  The result doesn't magically replace the string.

The simplest solution is something like:

```
with open(filename, "r") as file:
    result = [line.split(',') for line in file]
```

If you need both the pre-split lines and the post-split lines:

```
with open(filename, "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
result = [line.split(',') for line in lines]
```